# Missing Multichain.conf - How to create

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

C:\Users\kabir\Downloads\multichain-windows-2.0-beta-2>multichain-cli listpermissions all
error: No credentials found for chain "listpermissions"

You must set rpcpassword= in the configuration file:
C:\Users\kabir\AppData\Roaming\MultiChain\listpermissions/multichain.conf
If the file does not exist, create it with owner-readable-only file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the blockchain name after multichain-cli and before the command, e.g.:

multichain-cli chain1 listpermissions all